# Serve Gmail Attachments with Content Service

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using Google Apps Script and Content Service. I would like to provider users with a way to download an attachment for a given [Gmail Message](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message).

The [Gmail Attachment](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-attachment) objects doesn't expose a download URL like the [Site Attachment](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/attachment#getUrl%28%29) does so I'm trying to use Content Service to serve the bits for the attachment. Content Service appears to only support text and does not have an API for returning byte[].

Is there a work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1 
You can encode your attachments as Base64 using `Utilities.base64Encode()` and then decode it at the client end.

Option 2
Save the attachment to Drive, give appropriate permissions and give the link to download the attachment.

As an aside, ContentService is useful only if your attachments are not accessed manually i.e. they are accessed through another program. If your users are manuaaly invoking the script, they might as well be given a link to download the attachment

Comment: I was afraid those would be the only two options. [I petitioned Google for another option](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3268).